# How to place a button within another button (java)

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have been asked:

1. If it was possible to place a button within another button in a frame (with `JFrame`)
2. What happens when I try to do it (they ask to test if and tell what happens)

I have tried to do it, but I don't know how. The only thing I succeeded in doing was to put two buttons at the same place in `BorderLayout` (two buttons at "center" position for example, but I don't think it is the same thing as "one button within a button".

If someone knew if it is possible to do it or how to do it it would be great!

Comment: Can you not say no to 1?

Comment: I guess, but I still have to explain what happens if I try it !! (and I don't know how to do it )

Comment: You could make a clickable region drawn within another, but a JButton takes up a portion of the layout manager on its own, and therefore I think your answer would relate to how the button interacts with that, as well as, if you click on a particular button, would it click both?

Comment: A button is a container, in theory it can contain child components

Comment: Additionally, even the JavaDoc says that the `java.awt.Container` base class presents a stack ordering of components, so one button may be visually inside, but it's actually on top of another

Comment: you're right it would probably be something like that, but I'm not sure...how could I make a clickable region whithin another ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, one button can be added to another button. I'll leave you to investigate the second question.

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.net.*;

public class ButtonQuestion {

    private JComponent ui = null;
    JButton button1;
    JButton button2;

    ButtonQuestion() {
        try {
            initUI();
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void initUI() throws MalformedURLException {
        if (ui!=null) return;

        ui = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(4,4));
        ui.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(4,4,4,4));

        button1 = new JButton("button 1", new ImageIcon(
                new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/in9g1.png")));
        button2 = new JButton("button 2", new ImageIcon(
                new URL("https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCF8S.png")));
        ui.add(button1);
        // Yep. One button can indeed be added to another..
        button1.add(button2);
    }

    public JComponent getUI() {
        return ui;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception useDefault) {
                }
                ButtonQuestion o = new ButtonQuestion();

                JFrame f = new JFrame(o.getClass().getSimpleName());
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);

                f.setContentPane(o.getUI());
                f.pack();
                f.setMinimumSize(f.getSize());

                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```